# Android array-list currency list of countries

Tags: android, arrays, xml, currency, countries

I want to get the currency list of all the countries but could not find anywhere in the xml format. Does anybody knows from where can I get it?

Comment: You mean country list with currency code?

Comment: Yeah, I want the currency code..

Comment: check it might help you https://www.codepile.net/pile/9632zoxd
Credit to https://gist.github.com/tiagodealmeida/0b97ccf117252d742dddf098bc6cc58a

Comment: Actually, I just want the currency symbol and the currency code.

Answer (score 2):

You can you this gist for Country name & currency code
https://github.com/samayo/country-json/blob/master/src/country-by-currency-code.json

for currency symbol -
https://gist.github.com/ksafranski/2973986

--EDIT-- 
I think this will works for you
https://gist.github.com/nhalstead/4c1652563dd13357ab936fc97703c019